# Nesting subrouters in Gorilla Mux

Tags: go, routes, mux, gorilla

I've been using [`gorilla/mux`](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) for my routing needs. But I noticed one problem, when I nest multiple Subrouters it doesn't work.

Here is the example:

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    api := r.Path("/api").Subrouter()
    u := api.Path("/user").Subrouter()
    u.Methods("GET").HandleFunc(UserHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

I wanted to use this approach so I can delegate populating the router to some other package, for example `user.Populate(api)`

However this doesn't seem to work. It works only if I use single Subrouter in the chain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I figured it out, so I'll just post it here in case someone is as stupid as I was. :D

When creating path-based subrouter, you have to obtain it with `PathPrefix` instead of `Path`.

```
r.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
```

Use `r.Path("/api")` only when attaching handlers to that endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are struggling to split between auth and noauth routes, the following works fine for me:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()

noAuthRouter := r.MatcherFunc(func(r *http.Request, rm *mux.RouteMatch) bool {
    return r.Header.Get("Authorization") == ""
}).Subrouter()

authRouter := r.MatcherFunc(func(r *http.Request, rm *mux.RouteMatch) bool {
    return true
}).Subrouter()
```

Then you can apply middleware for authRouter only

Answer (score -1):

If you need to Separate out the UI and API routers, you can simply do what the OP suggested:

```
appRouter := r.PathPrefix("/").Subrouter()
appRouter.Use(myAppRouter)
apiRouter := r.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
apiRouter.Use(myAPIRouter)
```

Many thanks for the OP for providing the answer. Hopefully having it all in one place for my use case will help someone.